# How to get count for every 1 hour interval

Tags: postgresql

```
select
count("Status") as Total_Count

from "dbo"

where "Status" = 'Pass'

and "StartDateTime" BETWEEN '2020-11-01 15:00:00' AND '2020-11-01 16:00:00'

group by "Status"
```

[image]

How to get data for every 1 hour interval as in the image above? As currently i changing the time interval manualy. I want get the counts from 12am to 12am next day with 1 hour interval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=79a9e56916288f7ee1416ac8ea7d78fb)

When you truncate the start time with `date_trunc()` at the `hour` part, all times will be normalized to full hours. This can be used as the `GROUP BY` criterion.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    t
GROUP BY date_trunc('hour', starttime)
```

To format the time column as you expect, you can use the `to_char()` function:

```
SELECT
    to_char(date_trunc('hour', starttime), 'HH12:MI:SS AM') || ' - ' || to_char(date_trunc('hour', starttime)  + interval '1 hour', 'HH12:MI:SS AM'),
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    t
GROUP BY date_trunc('hour', starttime)
```